# Moodle loads white page TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, moodle, tcpdf

I want to genarate custom PDF in Moodle (and later develop it further with the data from every course). I read the examples for `TCPDF`, but the system throws `error` every time, when trying to test them.

In `printpdf.php` in my `local` `folder` I have:

```
require_once ('/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(P, 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetTitle('Example');
$pdf->SetProtection(array('modify'));
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
$pdf->AddPage();
```

When trying to call the page `mymoodle/local/custom/classes/printpdf.php` it shows me:

```
Warning: require_once(/tcpdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mymoodle\local\custom\classes\local\printpdf.php on line 24

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/tcpdf.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mymoodle\local\custom\classes\local\printpdf.php on line 24
```

Comment: Seems like you are not specifying the correct relative path to the libary in `require_once ('/tcpdf.php');`

Comment: The path of the `TCPDF` library in the folders is `mymoodle/lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php`, even `require_once ('lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');` won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not directly use the TCPDF library within Moodle - there is a wrapper around this that allows it to work correctly.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../config.php');
require_once($CFG->libdir.'/pdflib.php');

$pdf = new pdf();
```

Note that you may need to adjust the number of '/../' in the first line, depending on how deeply nested below the top-level directory you are.

Note also, that you appear to have placed your code inside the 'classes' directory, whilst not defining a PHP class; scripts to be directly accessed by the end user should be placed outside of the classes directory in your plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the config file first

> require_once('../../../../config.php');

Then load the library relative to the lib directory

> require_once($CFG->libdir . '/tcpdf.php');

Comment: Now shows additionally  `Notice: Undefined variable: CFG` and `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: This is because config.php is not loading. You have to put the path relative to your current file. I edit the answer trying to adjust to your case.